# How to compare an index to a row on python

Tags: python, date, pandas

I am trying to compare dates via index of df1 and the date range (left inclusive) via the 'Start Date' column on a df2 so that I can get the appropriate kwH value for it.

For example:

df1 consists of:

```
            50       51
4/3/2013    326.32   193.1
7/2/2013    324.2    192.1
3/5/2014    234.2    0
4/6/2015    302.1    23
```

^
(index)

df2 Consists of:

```
     Start Date  End Date     kWh    
 0   4/3/2013    5/3/2013     76,640 
 1   5/3/2013    9/7/2013     96,640  
 2   1/3/2014    4/7/2014     17,640   
 3   4/7/2014    8/7/2014     16,640 
 4   8/7/2014    2/3/2015     19,291
 5   2/3/2015    4/3/2015     18,291
 6   4/3/2015    5/7/2015     86,640
```

How do write another column(kWh) to df1 based on its date index that falls within the range of the 'Start Date' to 'End Date' columns on df2. (in this case only paying attention to the 'start date'(left inclusive)

For An Example:

```
            50       51     kWh
4/3/2013    326.32   193.1  76640
7/2/2013    324.2    192.1  96640
3/5/2014    234.2    0      17640
4/6/2015    302.1    23     86640
```

What is the simplest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

This will set the value of the 'kWh' col of `df1` to the sum of those kWh value from the `df2`, which start and end dates include the particular index of `df1`. Hope it helps

```
   df1['kWh'] = map(df2[(df2['Start Date'] >= x) & (df2['End Date'] < x)]['kWh'].sum, df1.index)
```

Comment: I am confused as to why you would sum?

Comment: Wel, there might be several rows in `df2`, which satisfy the condition given. If you are sure that there is one and only one row - just do without the `sum`, and in this case you also can remove the `map` operator

Comment: implementing this code I get `ValueError: No axis named 2013-04-03 00:00:00 for object type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`